# Debugging a Containerized Django App in PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, django-rest-framework, pycharm

I want to debug a containerized Django App in PyCharm

I've done the following:

1. Configure Docker settings
2. Set up a Remote Interpreter
3. Create a Run/Debug configuration to debug a Django app running inside of Docker

I've added the  run/debug configuration. When I'm trying to run my configuration, I get error running 'Run django': Python script path must be set

[Reference](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-debugging-pycharm/) of source tutorial